# Java: Accessing a String outside of a function

Tags: android, android-async-http, loopj

I am a hobby programmer and am trying to access returnJson outside of the onSuccess function. Inside of the function, I can see that it returns as expected. Could somebody explain why I cannot view it outside and what I can do to make it accessible on the outside?

```
String returnJson;
client.post(context, url, entity, "application/json", new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
        returnJson = response.toString();
    }
});

Log.d("get json",returnJson);
```

Comment: For  my use case, I had to redactor my code to be inside the on success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access it fine, but it is not initialized until the `onSuccess()` is called, which is likely *after* the `Log.d()` is called, due to `client.post()` being executed asyncronously.

Because of this, at the moment you try to log `returnJson`, it is not yet initialized and the logging won't work as you expect.

Comment: So how would I wait until after onSuccess is called?

Comment: @AWhippler Put the log in the onSuccess, or put it in a seperate method and call that method in the onSuccess

Answer (score -1):

You need to make `returnJson` a global variable.

Let's say this is what your class looks like:

```
public class MyClass {
    public void myMethod() {
        String returnJson;
        client.post(context, url, entity, "application/json", new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
                 returnJson = response.toString();
            }
        });
        Log.d("get json",returnJson);
    }
}
```

The `returnJson` variable is only initialized inside of the myMethod() method. To fix this, your class should look like this:

```
public class MyClass {
    String returnJson;
    public void myMethod() {
        client.post(context, url, entity, "application/json", new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
                 returnJson = response.toString();
            }
        });
        Log.d("get json",returnJson);
    }
}
```

So now it's a global variable and can be accesed from all your methods.
Enjoy!